# How to remove repositories from ViewVC commit database?

Tags: mysql, svn, viewvc

On a Debian system, my ViewVC database still refers to no longer accessible Subversion repositories (archived, moved to another server...)

Because it hosts a large number of repositories, I cannot delete and rebuild for all repositories.... it would be far to long, disk and CPU intensive. 1 Gb MySQL ViewVC database for 90 Gb of repositories.

So how to remove a repository selectively from a ViewVC database ?

Comment: Could you remove your repositories from configuration file ? In my case in /etc/viewvc/viewc.conf, there is all my repositories

Comment: Removing a repository from the configuration file will prevent browsing it in ViewVC, but ViewVC MySQL database still contains information collected by /usr/lib/viewvc/svndbadmin about that repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `svndbadmin purge REPOS-PATH`.

From the output of `svndbadmin` when not provided any arguments:

> Purge information specific to the repository located at REPOS-PATH from the database.

Assuming you have multiple repositories, this will allow you to purge the details for one specific repository without impacting the rest of your commit database.

Comment: Thank you. I feel stupid not having tried `svndbadmin --help` before asking...